# VBA Shell Alternative when CMD is disabled

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using VBA in Access to open a command line application through PowerShell. I can't use Shell() because the command prompt is disabled, but not PowerShell.

```
retval = Shell("powershell.exe", vbNormalFocus)
```

This command returns `Invalid Procedure Call or argument`

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("powershell.exe")
```

This command returns Access is denied no matter what application I try to open.

```
Application.FollowHyperlink "c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
```

This command returns the message `Unable to open c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe. No Program is registered to open this file.`

```
Dim wsh As WshShell
Set wsh = New WshShell
Debug.Print wsh.Run("powershell.exe", vbNormalFocus, True)
```

This gives returns `Permission denied.`

Tried [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Windows-API/determine-when-a-shelled-process-ends), but does nothing.

Comment: I've had good results calling PowerShell using Chip Pearson's ShellAndWait VBA module. You can get it here: http://www.cpearson.com/EXCEL/ShellAndWait.aspx. Maybe it will work in your environment.

Comment: Can you manually open a Powershell command window? It looks you do not have the necessary permisisons...

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, I actually open the command line application through PowerShell. I can even use the ISE. Just not CMD.exe

Comment: @RetiredGeek I am having some issues with that since some commands are for Excel specifically and not Access (Should of mentioned in OP). `XlEnableCancelKey` is specifically for Excel. Can't seem to find the Access alternative.

Comment: @RetiredGeek I tried commenting out those lines and running the code `Debug.Print ShellAndWait("powershell.exe", 10, vbMaximizedFocus, PromptUser)`, but just returns 1 and does not open Powershell. If I change to calc.exe for example, the calculator app opens fine.

Comment: Rick, is the directory for Powershell.exe in your Path? You could try providing the entire drive/path/powershell.exe in the command.

Comment: @RetiredGeek tried it. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Rick,

I tried this today and got it to work. I had to comment out a lot of lines of code so I've included the code and the lines already commented out.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' modShellAndWait
' By Chip Pearson, chip@cpearson.com, www.cpearson.com
' This page on the web site: www.cpearson.com/Excel/ShellAndWait.aspx
' 9-September-2008
'
' This module contains code for the ShellAndWait function that will Shell to a process
' and wait for that process to end before returning to the caller.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal hHandle As Long, _
    ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32.dll" ( _
    ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
    ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
    ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Private Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000

Public Enum ShellAndWaitResult
    Success = 0
    Failure = 1
    TimeOut = 2
    InvalidParameter = 3
    SysWaitAbandoned = 4
    UserWaitAbandoned = 5
    UserBreak = 6
End Enum

Public Enum ActionOnBreak
    IgnoreBreak = 0
    abandonwait = 1
    PromptUser = 2
End Enum

Private Const STATUS_ABANDONED_WAIT_0 As Long = &H80
Private Const STATUS_WAIT_0 As Long = &H0
Private Const WAIT_ABANDONED As Long = (STATUS_ABANDONED_WAIT_0 + 0)
Private Const WAIT_OBJECT_0 As Long = (STATUS_WAIT_0 + 0)
Private Const WAIT_TIMEOUT As Long = 258&
Private Const WAIT_FAILED As Long = &HFFFFFFFF
Private Const WAIT_INFINITE = -1&


Public Function ShellAndWait(ShellCommand As String, _
                    TimeOutMs As Long, _
                    ShellWindowState As VbAppWinStyle, _
                    BreakKey As ActionOnBreak) As ShellAndWaitResult
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' ShellAndWait
'
' This function calls Shell and passes to it the command text in ShellCommand. The function
' then waits for TimeOutMs (in milliseconds) to expire.
'
'   Parameters:
'       ShellCommand
'           is the command text to pass to the Shell function.
'
'       TimeOutMs
'           is the number of milliseconds to wait for the shell'd program to wait. If the
'           shell'd program terminates before TimeOutMs has expired, the function returns
'           ShellAndWaitResult.Success = 0. If TimeOutMs expires before the shell'd program
'           terminates, the return value is ShellAndWaitResult.TimeOut = 2.
'
'       ShellWindowState
'           is an item in VbAppWinStyle specifying the window state for the shell'd program.
'
'       BreakKey
'           is an item in ActionOnBreak indicating how to handle the application's cancel key
'           (Ctrl Break). If BreakKey is ActionOnBreak.AbandonWait and the user cancels, the
'           wait is abandoned and the result is ShellAndWaitResult.UserWaitAbandoned = 5.
'           If BreakKey is ActionOnBreak.IgnoreBreak, the cancel key is ignored. If
'           BreakKey is ActionOnBreak.PromptUser, the user is given a ?Continue? message. If the
'           user selects "do not continue", the function returns ShellAndWaitResult.UserBreak = 6.
'           If the user selects "continue", the wait is continued.
'
'   Return values:
'            ShellAndWaitResult.Success = 0
'               indicates the the process completed successfully.
'            ShellAndWaitResult.Failure = 1
'               indicates that the Wait operation failed due to a Windows error.
'            ShellAndWaitResult.TimeOut = 2
'               indicates that the TimeOutMs interval timed out the Wait.
'            ShellAndWaitResult.InvalidParameter = 3
'               indicates that an invalid value was passed to the procedure.
'            ShellAndWaitResult.SysWaitAbandoned = 4
'               indicates that the system abandoned the wait.
'            ShellAndWaitResult.UserWaitAbandoned = 5
'               indicates that the user abandoned the wait via the cancel key (Ctrl+Break).
'               This happens only if BreakKey is set to ActionOnBreak.AbandonWait.
'            ShellAndWaitResult.UserBreak = 6
'               indicates that the user broke out of the wait after being prompted with
'               a ?Continue message. This happens only if BreakKey is set to
'               ActionOnBreak.PromptUser.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim TaskID As Long
Dim ProcHandle As Long
Dim WaitRes As Long
Dim Ms As Long
Dim MsgRes As VbMsgBoxResult
'Dim SaveCancelKey As XlEnableCancelKey
Dim ElapsedTime As Long
Dim Quit As Boolean
Const ERR_BREAK_KEY = 18
Const DEFAULT_POLL_INTERVAL = 500

If Trim(ShellCommand) = vbNullString Then
    ShellAndWait = ShellAndWaitResult.InvalidParameter
    Exit Function
End If

If TimeOutMs < 0 Then
    ShellAndWait = ShellAndWaitResult.InvalidParameter
    Exit Function
ElseIf TimeOutMs = 0 Then
    Ms = WAIT_INFINITE
Else
    Ms = TimeOutMs
End If

Select Case BreakKey
    Case abandonwait, IgnoreBreak, PromptUser
        ' valid
    Case Else
        ShellAndWait = ShellAndWaitResult.InvalidParameter
        Exit Function
End Select

Select Case ShellWindowState
    Case vbHide, vbMaximizedFocus, vbMinimizedFocus, vbMinimizedNoFocus, vbNormalFocus, vbNormalNoFocus
        ' valid
    Case Else
        ShellAndWait = ShellAndWaitResult.InvalidParameter
        Exit Function
End Select

On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
TaskID = Shell(ShellCommand, ShellWindowState)
If (Err.Number <> 0) Or (TaskID = 0) Then
    ShellAndWait = ShellAndWaitResult.Failure
    Exit Function
End If

ProcHandle = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, False, TaskID)
If ProcHandle = 0 Then
    ShellAndWait = ShellAndWaitResult.Failure
    Exit Function
End If

On Error GoTo ErrH:
'SaveCancelKey = Application.EnableCancelKey
'Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
WaitRes = WaitForSingleObject(ProcHandle, DEFAULT_POLL_INTERVAL)
Do Until WaitRes = WAIT_OBJECT_0
    DoEvents
    Select Case WaitRes
        Case WAIT_ABANDONED
            ' Windows abandoned the wait
            ShellAndWait = ShellAndWaitResult.SysWaitAbandoned
            Exit Do
        Case WAIT_OBJECT_0
            ' Successful completion
            ShellAndWait = ShellAndWaitResult.Success
            Exit Do
        Case WAIT_FAILED
            ' attach failed
            ShellAndWait = ShellAndWaitResult.Failure
            Exit Do
        Case WAIT_TIMEOUT
            ' Wait timed out. Here, this time out is on DEFAULT_POLL_INTERVAL.
            ' See if ElapsedTime is greater than the user specified wait
            ' time out. If we have exceed that, get out with a TimeOut status.
            ' Otherwise, reissue as wait and continue.
            ElapsedTime = ElapsedTime + DEFAULT_POLL_INTERVAL
            If Ms > 0 Then
                ' user specified timeout
                If ElapsedTime > Ms Then
                    ShellAndWait = ShellAndWaitResult.TimeOut
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    ' user defined timeout has not expired.
                End If
            Else
                ' infinite wait -- do nothing
            End If
            ' reissue the Wait on ProcHandle
            WaitRes = WaitForSingleObject(ProcHandle, DEFAULT_POLL_INTERVAL)
            
        Case Else
            ' unknown result, assume failure
            ShellAndWait = ShellAndWaitResult.Failure
            Exit Do
            Quit = True
    End Select
Loop

CloseHandle ProcHandle
'Application.EnableCancelKey = SaveCancelKey
Exit Function

ErrH:
'Debug.Print "ErrH: Cancel: " & Application.EnableCancelKey
If Err.Number = ERR_BREAK_KEY Then
    If BreakKey = ActionOnBreak.abandonwait Then
        CloseHandle ProcHandle
        ShellAndWait = ShellAndWaitResult.UserWaitAbandoned
'        Application.EnableCancelKey = SaveCancelKey
        Exit Function
    ElseIf BreakKey = ActionOnBreak.IgnoreBreak Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume
    ElseIf BreakKey = ActionOnBreak.PromptUser Then
        MsgRes = MsgBox("User Process Break." & vbCrLf & _
            "Continue to wait?", vbYesNo)
        If MsgRes = vbNo Then
            CloseHandle ProcHandle
            ShellAndWait = ShellAndWaitResult.UserBreak
'            Application.EnableCancelKey = SaveCancelKey
        Else
            Err.Clear
            Resume Next
        End If
    Else
        CloseHandle ProcHandle
'        Application.EnableCancelKey = SaveCancelKey
        ShellAndWait = ShellAndWaitResult.Failure
    End If
Else
    ' some other error. assume failure
    CloseHandle ProcHandle
    ShellAndWait = ShellAndWaitResult.Failure
End If

'Application.EnableCancelKey = SaveCancelKey

End Function
```

Note: you'll see in the attached screenshot that to get a zero return (success) I had to increase the wait time considerably as 10 milliseconds was not enough time to type Exit into powershell, even as fast a typist as I am...LOL! Thus, the line of 2's (timeouts) below the zero.
[image]
HTH

Comment: I tried this, but still seems to be blocked. It returns 1. Funny, if I change to `notepad.exe` it opens fine and waits until I close it.

Comment: What anti-virus are you using? I didn't mention it before but Malwarebytes  blocks the call. I had to turn it off to run the code. It runs fine with Windows Defender though.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Set shellwindows = GetObject("new:9ba05972-f6a8-11cf-a442-00a0c90a8f39")
 Set itemobj = shellwindows.Item()
 itemobj.document.Application.ShellExecute sTempBAT, "", "", "open", 0
```

The above mentioned code will work to bypass the windows defender security
https://blog.sevagas.com/IMG/pdf/bypass_windows_defender_attack_surface_reduction.pdf

Comment: I added the lines `Dim shellwindows, itemobj`
`Dim sTempBAT As String` and tried to run powershell, but it didn't open. I tried changing the location of thecalculator pointing to it from the sTempBAT and it does open.